# How to bundle Flash player plugin with my Qt app and point QtWebKit to that path?

Tags: qt, flash, qtwebkit

I am trying to build a cross-platform Qt app where I need to show some flash content in a QWebPage. Is it possible to bundle the Flash player plugin within my app so that there is no dependency on whether the correct version of the plugin is already installed? I would probably also need to point QtWebKit to that particular path so it doesn't fail to find the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[QCoreApplication::addLibraryPath()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QCoreApplication.html) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an official way to do this, the documentation doesn't seem to mention any way to change the [plugin search paths](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html#netscape-plugin-support).

You may also want to look at [this question on changing the paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139983/add-a-new-plugins-path-to-qtwebkit) which suggests setting the environment variable `QTWEBKIT_PLUGIN_PATH` or calling non-API methods.